# Jenkins pipeline - How to run a stage based on defined parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a jenkins pipeline that includes few stages- I wish to run the copy_file stage only if **deploy** parameter == yes.  I have tried to use when but it is not working

```
servers =['100.1.1.1', '100.1.1.2']
deploy = yes

pipeline {
    agent { label 'server-1' }

    stages {
        stage('Connect to git') {
            steps {
                    git branch: 'xxxx', credentialsId: 'yyy', url: 'https://zzzz'
            }
        }
        stage ('Copy file') {
            when { deploy == 'yes' }
            steps {
                dir('folder_a') {
                    file_copy(servers)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def file_copy(list) {
    list.each { item ->
        sh "echo Copy file"
        sh "scp 11.txt user@${item}:/data/"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, declare an environmental variable.

```
environment {
    DEPLOY = 'YES'
}
```

Now use it in when condition like this.

```
when { environment name: 'DEPLOY', value: 'YES' }
```

There are two types of pipeline codes in Jenkins.

1. Declarative pipeline
2. Scripted pipeline (groovy script)

You are coding in declarative manner so you need to follow the declarative syntax.

**NOTE: There are other ways for what you are trying to achieve. I mean to say you may use different logic.**

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use parameters:

```
parameters { 
   choice choices: ['YES', 'NO'], description: 'Deploy?', name: 'DEPLOY'
}
stages {
  stage ('continue if DEPLOY set to YES') {
    when {
      expression { params.DEPLOY == 'YES' }
    }
    steps {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```